# Doctrine2 + soft delete as a state pattern

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, soft-delete, state-pattern

Doctrine2 docs said that soft-delete behavior should be better implemented as a *State pattern* But not provide any example of that implementation.

How to achieve soft delete behavior using a state pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they refer to [filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) which are available since version 2.2:

> The filter functionality works on SQL level. Whether an SQL query is
>   generated in a Persister, during lazy loading, in extra lazy
>   collections or from DQL. Each time the system iterates over all the
>   enabled filters, adding a new SQL part as a filter returns.

The [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) library includes a ["soft-delete" behaviour](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md). You might want to have a look at their [implementation](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/Filter/SoftDeleteableFilter.php) to see how it works in detail.